# Stack objects being inserted into containers?

Tags: c++, vector

In C++ what happens if you create an object on the stack (within a function) and insert it into a heap-allocated container (which has been passed into the function/exists after the function finishes)?

The stack object has local scope, but the container it has been inserted within, is on the heap and can last after the function (where the insert was made) has returned. Is the stack object still retrievable from the container after the function returns?

```
void Test( std::vector<MyClass>& myvec )
{
    MyClass m;
    myvec.push_back(m);
}
```

Comment: I believe that when you leave the function, the stack-allocated object is destroyed leaving the heap-allocated object with a bad reference.

Comment: `myvec` *also* has local scope...

Comment: `public void` is not C++. This is pseudo-code... and what is `Vector`? Please provide its definition.

Comment: @EJK: The vector doesn't hold references though.

Comment: Yes I just quickly knocked up the code without testing it. Can someone modify it for me? I clicked "edit" but the code is not there :s

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: How do you know? We don't know the definition of `Vector`.

Comment: @KerrekSB: Because I read intentions, I don't take every thing I read literally.

Comment: @user997112 I've change the parameter to be a reference to std::vector as I think that is what you were intending to ask.  Hope that's ok.

Comment: @Steve I didnt realise it would affect the answer. I thought just whether it stored pointers or copies would affect the answer.

Comment: @user997112 if myvec is not a reference then it means that myvec is passed by value.  That is when the method starts `myvec` is an empty vector.  When the method exits it is then destructed.  For this simple example, it would mean that nothing of consequence actually happens.

Comment: @user997112: The problem is, if it's `Vector`, rather than `std::vector`, we don't know what that is.  Maybe it does store pointers.  Just because the template parameter type was `MyClass`, that doesn't mean it stores `MyClass` objects.  Its `push_back` member could take objects in by reference, then take their address and store that in its internal storage.  That's what KerrekSB was hinting at with his comment.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley it was supposed to be std::vector

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this particular case, `m` will be copy-constructed into a new instance of `MyClass`, which will be owned by the vector.  So a *different but equivalent* instance of `MyClass` can be retrieved from the vector, yes.

Comment: How do you know that? We don't know the definition of `Vector`.

Comment: and is that because I used Vector<Myclass> rather than Vector<*MyClass>?

Comment: @user997112: `template <typename T> struct Vector { void push_back(T const & x) { p = &x; } T * p; };`?!

Comment: @user997112 If it was a vector of pointers, and you did `myvec.push_back(&m)` then yes, this would invoke undefined behavior (a very bad thing).

Comment: @user997112: But what is this `Vector` template? Is it something you hacked up? You could have given it any kind of insane behaviour we cannot guess.

Comment: @user997112: But then you misspelled it. That one is called `std::vector`.

Answer (score 2):

```
Is the stack object still retrievable from the container after the function returns?
```

Yes, your `myvec.push_back(m);` makes a copy of m and a new copy is manged by vector.

However, after your function returns `myvec` doesn't have `m` inside because you pass `myvec` into Test function by value, `Test` function makes a temporary copy of `myvec` and copy `m` into it, after function returns the temporary copy of `myvec` is released. So you meant to pass `myvec` to `Test` function by reference as below:

```
public void Test(Vector<MyClass>& myvec){
    MyClass m;
    myvec.push_back(m);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Base assumption: when you use `Vector`, you really mean `std::vector`. The answer *could* change with a container that's designed enough differently.

As long as you do like you usually should, and store objects (not pointers) in the container, you're all right, because what's stored in the container is normally a copy of the object you pass.

Under the right circumstances, the object in the container can be move constructed from what you pass, but the effect is basically the same -- you end up with an object whose lifetime continues until it's removed from the container (or the container is destroyed, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

As noted by other answers, `m` is copied into vector. That said, your function receives vector by value too (UPD: it was true for the original code, which was edited since), and it's obviously not what you wanted.

Comment: I did try to edit the code but strangely it doesnt show me the code when i click edit. So the answer all depends whether the vector is passed by reference or value? as well as whether it contains pointers or copies?

Comment: According to your definition, vector contains copies, not pointers. The problem is that (in the old version of your code) you changed a *copy* of a vector, so these changes won't be visible outside.

Answer (score 0):

The code in the question will create a *copy* of `MyClass` in the `std::vector`.  The original `m` will be destructed when the `Test` method exits.

If we change the vector to store pointers to `MyClass` we have two possible options.

```
void Test( std::vector<MyClass*>& myvec )
{
    // Allocates a new MyClass on the heap.
    MyClass* pM = new MyClass();
    myvec.push_back(pM);

    // This variable will be allocated on the stack and cleaned up on method exit
    MyClass dontDoThis;
    myvec.push_back(&dontDoThis);
}
```

At the end of this method `myvec` has two elements, `myvec[0]` and `myvec[1]`.

When a container of pointers is stored then the object *must* be allocated so that it is valid for the length of time the pointer is in the container.  In the example above the `pM` pointer will be valid after the `Test` method exits.  This means that `myvec[0]` will be a valid pointer after the method exits.

Initially, a valid pointer to `dontDoThis` variable will be added to the vector, but when the method exits the destructor of `dontDoThis` will be called and the memory will probably be used to store other data.  The pointer in `myvec` looks ok, but any attempt to actually use it will cause undefined behaviour.  On method exit the pointer in `myvec[1]` might look valid, but actually it points to junk.

Note that at a later time, when `myvec[0]` is changed or deleted, it is important to call:

```
delete myvec[0]
```

to ensure that the object is cleaned up properly.  Otherwise a memory leak will occur.

After explaining what will happen with naked pointers, I strongly recommend you use smart pointers such as [std::unique_ptr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) and [std::shared_ptr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr)

Answer (score 0):

Is the stack object still retrievable from the container after the function returns?

Only if MyClass has a "gut" copy constructor. (Deep copy or sharing ownedship of other resuorses, etc)

I mean, it could be retrived but it could be in a broked state